# How to add Datasource in SOAP UI open source or OS /free version?

Tags: excel, soap, groovy, datasource, soapui

How to add Datasource in SOAP UI open source or OS /free version?
(I know how to do in pro version, saw many solutions how to do that but I have the OS version for which there is no option to do so?
in pro it is-> testcase-> add step->datasource 
but in OS there is no option -Datasource in add step

Answer (score 0):

Data Source is only in the PRO version ( [Link](https://www.soapui.org/professional/soapui-pro/why-go-pro.html) )

You can use groovy otherwise